# Analytic solution to the following system of PDE

Tags: differential-equations

Is there a smooth vector field $u: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $$
\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t}u +\lambda\left(u \times \bigtriangledown u\right)  =   \mu \bigtriangleup u.~~~~~~~~~\lambda\neq 0~~~~~\mu >0 $$ with initial condition $$u(x,0) = u_0(x).$$ The operation $\times$ is the usual cross product in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So equivelently, \begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial }{ \partial t}
\begin{bmatrix}
 u_1 \\
u_2 \\
 u_3
\end{bmatrix}
+ 
\lambda\begin{bmatrix}
 u_2 \dfrac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}-u_3 \dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}  \\
u_3\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}-u_1 \dfrac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3} \\
  u_1\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}- u_2\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1} 
\end{bmatrix}
= \mu \bigtriangleup \begin{bmatrix}
  u_1  \\
   u_2 \\
   u_3 
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Here $\bigtriangleup $ is the Laplacian operator and $\bigtriangledown u$ is the gradient of $u$ given as $\bigtriangledown u = \left[\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1},\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2},\dfrac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}\right]$. So for example, $\bigtriangleup u_1 = \dfrac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x_1^2}+ \dfrac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x_2^2}+ \dfrac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x_3^2}$.

Someone mentioned possibly using an Inverse scattering transform theorem but I am not to familiar on how to apply it to a system of PDE.

I would like to make a stab at this bad boy (when $\text{Div}(u) = 0$ but I do not know how far it will lead, Someone needs to peer review this.

Here it goes: Assume existence $u$ that satisfies the hypothesis (the proposed IVP). Then note that $u\perp (u\times \bigtriangledown u)$ for any point in time and space. Then it follows that by taking the dot product of both sides of the proposed equation one finds $$\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t} u\cdot u + \lambda \underbrace{(u\times \bigtriangledown u \cdot u)}_{=0}  = \mu ~ \bigtriangleup  u~\cdot ~u$$ Thus $u$ must satisfy $$\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t} u\cdot u = \mu ~  \bigtriangleup u\cdot u.$$ Now $u\cdot u = u = \|u\|~\cdot \|u\| = u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2$ because $u$ has the same direction as $u$ (the angle between them is zero). Hence, $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\biggl( u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2 \biggr)
 = \mu\biggl(u_1 \dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}+ u_2 \dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}+u_3 \dfrac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}\biggr).$$ Assume a solution of the form $$u = \phi(x,t) = \left(\phi_1(x_1,t),\phi_1(x_2,t),+\phi_3(x_3,t)\right).$$ Then $u_i = \dfrac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial x_i}$. The transformations takes the vector $u$ and maps it $\phi_i$ a solution to $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\biggl( \phi_1^2+\phi_2^2+\phi_3^2 \biggr)
 = \mu \bigtriangledown\biggl(\phi_1^2+ \phi_2^2+\phi_3^2\biggr).$$ Thus $$\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t}\|\phi\|^2 = \mu \bigtriangledown  \|\phi\|^2 .$$ One can easily deduce an analytic formula for $\|\phi\|^2$ by using the solution to the heat equation.

Comment: The usual cross product in $\mathbb{R}^3$ multiplies two vectors. $\nabla u$ is a rank 2 tensor, not a vector. Looking at your "equivalently" formula I don't understand its meaning. If you treat it as the cross product between $u$ and $(\partial_1 u_1, \partial_2 u_2, \partial_3 u_3)$, the middle term should be the negative of what you wrote. Can you clarify?

Comment: @ Willie Wong. The vector $\nabla u$ is the graident of $u$ which is a rank 1 tensor.  I wrote the formula in matrix format directly below.

Comment: @ Willie Wong. Thanks for mentioning that Typo.  I fixed it now.

Comment: I have added some work to the problem someone can try to help me think.

Comment: @MrPie There are very strange manipulations in your calculations (it seems that for you $(\tfrac{\partial }{\partial t} u)\cdot u = \tfrac{\partial }{\partial t} (u\cdot u)$ and the second derivatives in the term proportional to $\mu$ suddenly become first derivatives). Also, the motivation behind your non-rotationally invariant expression $\bigtriangledown u$ is not clear. This makes me think that this is not a research level question and that you might be better served by asking more focused questions about vector calculus on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @ Igor khavkine It is a research level question I will post from paper I found on September 2

Comment: Your computations have some mistakes in them. Laplacian is second order so what you did was not okay. The correct argument requires integrating on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and using the integration by parts formula to yield $$ \frac12 \frac{d}{dt} \|u\|_{L^2}^2 = - \mu \| D u \|_{L^2}^2 $$, showing monotonic decay of $L^2$ norm. (Here $Du$ is the full rank-two tensor of the derivative of the vector field $u$). For local in time existence and uniqueness, you can treat your equation as a nonlinear heat equation...

Comment: ... in the same way as how people solve Navier-Stokes. In fact, it is easier because you don't have to deal with the Leray projection (via the Oseen tensor). I am pretty sure the same argument also gives you small data global existence for some suitable initial function space.

Comment: How can you show the norms smooth existence implies smooth components. Like two components can blow up one to positive infinity and the other two negative infinity and cancel out someone