# A problem involving a highly non linear system of PDE

Tags: differential-equations, differential-operators

Is there a unique smooth function $u:\mathbb{R}^3:\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2\right) & = & \mu \left(u_1\dfrac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial u_1^2}+u_2\dfrac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x_2^2}+u_3\dfrac{\partial^2 u_3}{\partial x_3^2}\right),\label{1}\tag{$a$}\\
 \\
0 & = & \dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial u_1}+\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}+\dfrac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3},\label{2}\tag{$b$}\\
\\
0 & = &  u_1\biggl( u_2 \dfrac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}-u_3 \dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}  \biggr)+u_2\biggl(u_1 \dfrac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}- u_3\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1} \biggr)+u_3\biggl(  u_1\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}- u_2\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1} \biggr), \label{3}\tag{$c$}
  \end{eqnarray} 
$$
with boundary conditon $$u(x_0) = u_0(x).$$

Comment: Grhmm ! Seems to come from Navier-Stokes ...

Comment: It comes from earlier work we have done on this site. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402914/analytic-solution-to-the-following-system-of-pde